Cabinet fit help
We have a home office we are looking to add some cabinets/storage to. We were going to go with this unit from IKEA and get four of them, but that would be about 3 inches too wide. The wall size is 187 1/2 - 187 3/4 inches too long. How can we fit these cabinets in the space?

This is not a shopping question any longer.  The reference for shopping help has been removed.  This is purely a question of help with fitment.

Scroll down the page and there is a cabinet that is slightly smaller.  There is a unit that is longer as well.
Since there is no magic that can shrink one of the 4 cabinets you want, You need to come up with a combination that fits in the allowed space.
